# How can I only show the icons and not the text when sidebar is compressed

Tags: html, css, sidebar

[here's how it looks like when expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J6GX.png)

**I want to hide the text and only show the icons when sidebar menu is toggled and sidebar container is *compressed***

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="sidebar">
    <a th:href="@{/dashboard/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-home"></span>Dashboard</a>
    <a th:href="@{/profile/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-user"></span>Admin Profile</a>
    <a th:href="@{/notification/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-bell"></span>Notifications</a>
    <a th:href="@{/account/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-users"></span>User Accounts</a>
    <a th:href="@{/product/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-list"></span>Product List</a>
    <a th:href="@{/order/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span>Transactions</a>
    <a th:href="@{/report/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-chart-line"></span>Sales report</a>
</div>
```

**Please help**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="sidebar compressed">
<a th:href="@{/dashboard/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-home"></span><span class="menu-text">Dashboard</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/profile/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-user"></span><span class="menu-text">Admin Profile</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/notification/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-bell"></span><span class="menu-text">Notifications</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/account/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-users"></span><span class="menu-text">User Accounts</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/product/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-list"></span><span class="menu-text">Product List</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/order/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span><span class="menu-text">Transactions</span></a>
<a th:href="@{/report/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-chart-line"></span><span class="menu-text">Sales report</span></a>
```

wrap the text in **span** and add compressed class when sidebar is compressed and remove the class when sidebar is expanded. Then add below css:

.sidebar.compressed .menu-text{display:none}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a css selector to target text nodes. (There is an experimental feature called ::target-text, but this will not help you in this case anyway).

You should wrap the text in an element (most likely a `span`) and then use a selector for that to show/hide the text.

Answer (score 0):

Below a possible solution for your issue.

- I've wrappen a `span` around the text of the navbar items to easily address them using CSS.
- The word 'compress' is used to allow the text to disappear. You need to hover it with the mouse.
- Required CSS is added to let the text disappear.

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fas {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#compress:hover~a>.nav-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="compress">Compress</div>
  <a th:href="@{/dashboard/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-home"></span><span class="nav-text">Dashboard</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/profile/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-user"></span><span class="nav-text">Admin Profile</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/notification/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-bell"></span><span class="nav-text">Notifications</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/account/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-users"></span><span class="nav-text">User Accounts</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/product/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-list"></span><span class="nav-text">Product List</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/order/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span><span class="nav-text">Transactions</span></a>
  <a th:href="@{/report/}" class="sidebar-menu"><span class="fas fa-chart-line"></span><span class="nav-text">Sales report</span></a>
</div>
```